# HBase with MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have set up a HBase cluster over hadoop cluster where IPv6 is disabled in all nodes.

Everything is running fine; I am able to run java client to access HBase using standard Put, Scan, Get, ...

I wrote a map-reduce program to access HBase, But I have got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.reverseDns(DNS.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.reverseDNS(TableInp...
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.reverseDNS(TableInp...
```

This is my /etc/hosts file in all nodes:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
192.168.0.252   master.hadoop.com       master
192.168.0.251   slave.hadoop.com        slave
```

And this is my map-reduce client program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class HBaseAndMapReduceExample {

  public static class MyMapper extends TableMapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> {
    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      // this example is just copying the data from the source table...
      context.write(row, resultToPut(row,value));
    }

    private static Put resultToPut(ImmutableBytesWritable key, Result result) throws IOException {
      Put put = new Put(key.get());
      for (KeyValue kv : result.raw()) {
        put.add(kv);
      }

      return put;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    Job job = new Job(config,"HBaseAndMapReduceExample");
    job.setJarByClass(HBaseAndMapReduceExample.class);  // class that contains mapper

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setCaching(500);  // 1 is the default in Scan, which will be bad for MapReduce jobs
    scan.setCacheBlocks(false);  // don't set to true for MR jobs
    // set other scan attrs

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
    "testtable",      // input table
    scan,             // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
    MyMapper.class,   // mapper class
    null,             // mapper output key
    null,             // mapper output value
    job);

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
    "testtable2",     // output table
    null,             // reducer class
    job);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    if (!b) {
      throw new IOException("error with job!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify which version of Hadoop (0.22,0.23, 1.0, etc.) and HBase (0.90, 0.92, 94) you're using?

Comment: A more detailed stack trace would be helpful. First check your network settings against `http://hbase.apache.org/configuration.html#os` . You may find this article also useful: `http://sujee.net/tech/articles/hadoop/hadoop-dns/`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using hadoop 1.0, hostname and /etc/hosts also ssh trustship all are fine, I can ping/ssh any node using its name.

HBase code and mapreduce programs all are working fine except when I combine the mapreduce with hbase as shown in the previous example, then only there is a problem.

I've noticed now that this problem is not always there, sometimes it works sometimes it does not, and when it works it gives an error but it pursue the execution normally?!!

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Also try adding your zookeeper address :

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
   conf.setStrings("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",
            "your-zookeeper-addr");
Job job = new Job(config,"HBaseAndMapReduceExample");
```